# How to filter Observable Collection Class Collection

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, filter, observablecollection

I have implemented Linq-To-Sql..
Add necessary table in it...
after that linq class will automatically set property for field..
I implemented one class using `ObservableCollection` class.. and pass datacontextclass object in its constructor...

so after getting all data how to filter it?

```
  public class BindBookIssueDetails : ObservableCollection
        {
            public BindBookIssueDetails(DataClasses1DataContext dataDC)
            {
                foreach (Resource_Allocation_View res in dataDC.Resource_Allocation_Views)
                {
                    this.Add(res);
                }
            }
        }
```

```
private BindBookIssueDetails bResource;
bResource = new BindBookIssueDetails(db);
_cmbResource.ItemSource=bResource;
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `CollectionViewSource` and filter it. So that it affect only at the View(.XAML) side

```
    ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(bResource);
    collectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(YourFilterFunction);
```

Check out this blog for more details. http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use @Jobi's solution but for some reason I got an exception trying to fire `FilterFunction`.

So I used a slightly different approach. I cast `CollectionViewSource`'s `DefaultView` to a `BindingListCollectionView`

```
myVS=(BindingListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(sourceofdata);
```

and now I can construct an SQL-like filter string and apply it like that:

```
myVS.CustomFilter=myfilterstring;
```

I will still try to resolve my problem (I presume @Jobi's solution is more flexible).