# ObservableCollection<T> consisting of other 7 other ObservableCollection<T> s collections

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I will have a 7 small "shopping lists" and then one big containing all the items from the 7 small ones.

Is it possible to use databind and observablecollection so whatever is added/removed/changed from the small lists are updated in the big list?

```
public ObservableCollection<ShopItem> MondayShopList{ get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<ShopItem> TuesdayShopList{ get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<ShopItem> WedensdayShopList{ get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<ShopItem> ....
public ObservableCollection<ShopItem> TotalShopList { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i see 3 alternatives for you...

1. implement a composite ObservableCollection. if there isn't such a thing out there, you can build one by implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`
2. load all items into the total list and respond yourself to the collection changed events of the dayweek collections and make updates to the complete collection
3. perform a small architectural change and attach weekday information to the ShopItem. now you can keep them all in one list and display filtered sections of the big list.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m28XgTvj how would you in that list only show those with ShopItem.Day == 1

Comment: I haven't tested, but explore the functionality surrounding CollectionView and CollectionViewSource, which gives you filtering capabilities, etc. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303376/how-to-filter-observable-collection-class-collection

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to databind nested collections, if not by using `WPF TreeView` control that supports hierarchical data binding. If you want to show the content of child collections, bind them separately to `Ui`. The fact that they are childs of another is the matter of code-behind and not necessary should reflect its *exact* relationship rapresentation on `Ui`.

For concrete help with implementations of those scenarios look on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx)

Comment: That's not true, you can use the `TreeView` control to represent a collection of collections.

Comment: @m-y: you create tough constrain to use *one specific* control to resolve this problem. The question is general. The general solution for this, is to *slice* your data model between different controls, were `TreeView` control is able to host hierarchical data by itself is a kind of special case.

Comment: I was just commenting on the sentence in your answer: "No it's not possible to databind nested collections." I wasn't stating that the OP should go this route, just stating that it *is* to represent a collection of collections in the UI.